# Mapping a bi-dimentional array via class object in shared memory (WINAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi, mapping, shared-memory

Assuming I have the class:

```
class Labyrinth{
     int maze[100][100];
 }
```

How do I map an object from this class, let's say:

```
labyrinth a;
```

to shared memory using  `CreateFileMapping`  and  `MapViewOfFile`  ?

Also, after I mapped it on the shared memory, how would I access it? Via the pointer that  `MapViewOfFile`  returns would suffice?

Edit: I know that I can't use pointers (therefore, polymorphism and other classes that use pointers) in shared memory if another process is set to access it as well.

Comment: `void* p = MapViewOfFile( ... ); Labyrinth& a = *reinterpret_cast<Labyrinth*>( p );` is one way to map structured data onto flat memory. Objects you put into shared memory can contain pointers. It is necessary, though, that they only contain POD's (integral data types and structures). A common convention is to use the `struct` keyword when dealing with POD structures.

Comment: @IInspectable Objects in shared memory can contain pointers? I believe it's only safe to store offsets in shared memory.

Comment: @MarcSherman: Like the OP you are mixing up two concepts: Transferring pointers and dereferencing pointers. Transferring pointers from one process to another process is completely safe. Dereferencing a pointer from process A in process B, on the other hand, exhibits undefined behavior. You can still use that pointer in process B, e.g. to send it back to process A, or to check against `NULL`, but you must not dereference it.

Comment: @IInspectable Those use cases for transferring pointers but not dereferencing them are unrealistic.

Comment: @MarcSherman: Realistic or not doesn't make a difference (sharing a pointer to be used as a reference to an object in the source process is anything but unrealistic). The point is: Transferring pointers is safe. Dereferencing pointers outside their source process isn't. You need to keep those concepts separate.

Comment: @IInspectable In that use case then the pointer becomes an identifier and should be typed as something other than a pointer. Otherwise, someone will eventually write code that dereferences it in the wrong process. Even worse, if the source process crashes or terminates, then restarts, and maps to the *pre-existing* shared memory segment, it will dereference a pointer that is no longer valid since this is a *new* instance of the source process.

Comment: @MarcSherman: Now you're turning the question around to make it fit your answer. This doesn't change facts, though: You can transfer any POD (including pointers) between processes. Whether it is a good idea to do so is another question altogether, one that hadn't been raised.

Comment: Do you still wait for an answer?